# BLE Communication Protocol T1S (Smart Band) Get Data

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to communicate my android app to this smart band (T1S), I've already paired it, but I don't know how to extract data from it, such as temperature, etc.
I got the characteristics and services from it:

> {"name":"T1S","id":"F4:C3:33:99:21:5D","advertising":{},"rssi":-78,"services":["1801","1800","6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","1812","fee7"],"characteristics":[{"service":"1801","characteristic":"2a05","properties":["Broadcast","Read","Write","Notify","Indicate","AuthenticateSignedWrites"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]},{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a00","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a01","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a02","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2a04","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1800","characteristic":"2aa6","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","characteristic":"6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","properties":["Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]},{"service":"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","characteristic":"6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e","properties":["WriteWithoutResponse","Write"]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4e","properties":["Read","WriteWithoutResponse"]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4d","properties":["Read","Write","Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"},{"uuid":"2908"}]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4d","properties":["Read","Write","Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"},{"uuid":"2908"}]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4d","properties":["Read","Write","Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"},{"uuid":"2908"}]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4b","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a33","properties":["Read","Write","Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4a","properties":["Read"]},{"service":"1812","characteristic":"2a4c","properties":["WriteWithoutResponse"]},{"service":"fee7","characteristic":"fec9","properties":["Read","Notify"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]},{"service":"fee7","characteristic":"fea1","properties":["Read","Indicate"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]},{"service":"fee7","characteristic":"fea2","properties":["Read","Write","Indicate"],"descriptors":[{"uuid":"2902"}]}]}

I've analyzed another android apps and I captured received and sended bluetooth data with this smart band and my phone with Wireshark and bluetooth-log to know what data or protocols are transmitted to get the temperature, I'm sure that the response of temperature is:

> 0000   02 02 20 14 00 10 00 04 00 1b 12 00 ab 00 0a ff   ..
>   ............. 0010   51 13 14 06 05 06 37 24 05
>   Q.....7$.

[image]

But I don't know how to convert this response to actual temperature in C°, somebody knows how to extract the real data from this smart band?

thanks in advance.

[image]

smart band link:
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Cheap-High-Quantity-Bluetooth-Smart-Bracelet_1600057978967.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.111720.6.54226ef9FPTgvq

Answer (score 0):

```
const readCharacteristic = await device.readCharacteristicForService(userDataServiceUUID, heightCharacteristicUUID); // assuming the device is already connected
const heightInCentimeters = Buffer.from(readCharacteristic.value, 'base64').readUInt16LE(0);
```

https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/=--FAQ:-Passing-And-Retrieving-Of-Characteristic-Value